# Multiple Message Inspectors for each service endpoint

Tags: wcf

If a WCF service exposes three endpoints, then can we have different message inspectors for each endpoint? If yes then how can we apply on each endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create an endpoint behavior to apply a formatter you want.

```
class CustomInspectorEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomFormatter());
    }

    ...
}
```

Or if there is a general logic, you can apply a behavior for each of the endpoints using a service behavior class:

```
class MultipleInspectorsServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
            foreach (var endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
                endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomInspectorEndpointBehavior());
    }

    ...
}
```

Finally, you can apply endpoint behaviors from code...

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TheService));

foreach (var endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
    endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomInspectorEndpointBehavior(c));
```

(in case of service behavior)

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TheService));

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new MultipleInspectorsServiceBehavior());
```

...Or from config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="customInspectorEndpointBehavior"
           type="CustomInspectorEndpointBehaviorExtensionElement, MyAssembly" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="behavior1">
        <customInspectorEndpointBehavior />
        <!--maybe some other behaviors-->
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="behavior2">
        <customInspectorEndpointBehavior />
        <!--maybe some other behaviors-->
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="TheService">
      <endpoint address="address1" ... contract="..." behaviorConfiguration="behavior1" />
      <endpoint address="address2" ... contract="..." behaviorConfiguration="behavior1" />
      <endpoint address="address3" ... contract="..." behaviorConfiguration="behavior2" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

For service behavior:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="multipleInspectorsServiceBehavior"
           type="MultipleInspectorsServiceBehaviorExtensionElement, MyAssembly" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CustomServiceBehavior">
        <multipleInspectorsServiceBehavior />
      <!--maybe some others-->
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="TheService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="address1" ... contract="..." />
      <endpoint address="address2" ... contract="..." />
      <endpoint address="address3" ... contract="..." />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here you should create a [BehaviorExtensionElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.behaviorextensionelement.aspx) to reference behaviors in the config:

```
class CustomInspectorEndpointBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomInspectorEndpointBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new CustomInspectorEndpointBehavior();
    }
}

class MultipleInspectorsServiceBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(MultipleInspectorsServiceBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new MultipleInspectorsServiceBehavior();
    }
}
```